# Can this breadth-first search be made faster?

Tags: python, algorithm, computer-science, breadth-first-search

I have a data set which is a large unweighted cyclic graph The cycles occur in loops of about 5-6 paths. It consists of about 8000 nodes and each node has from 1-6 (usually about 4-5) connections. I'm doing single pair shortest path calculations and have implemented the following code to do a breadth-first search.

```
from Queue import Queue

q = Queue()
parent = {}
fromNode = 'E1123'
toNode = 'A3455'

# path finding
q.put(fromNode)
parent[fromNode] = 'Root'

while not q.empty():
  # get the next node and add its neighbours to queue
  current = q.get()
  for i in getNeighbours(current):
    # note parent and only continue if not already visited
    if i[0] not in parent:
      parent[i[0]] = current
      q.put(i[0])

  # check if destination
  if current == toNode:
    print 'arrived at', toNode
    break
```

The above code uses the Python 2.6 Queue module and getNeighbours() is simply a subroutine that makes a single MySQL call and returns the neighbours as a list of tuples e.g. (('foo',),('bar',)). The SQL call is quick.

The code works ok however testing to down to depths of about 7 layers takes about 20 seconds to run (2.5GHz Intel 4GB RAM OS X 10.6)

I'd welcome any comments about how to improve the run time of this code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, given the upvotes on the comment, I'll make it an answer now.

The SQL in the tight loop is **definitely** slowing you down. I don't care how fast the call is. Think about it -- you're asking for a query to be parsed, a lookup to be run -- as fast as that is, it's still in a tight loop. What does your data set look like? Can you just `SELECT` the entire data set into memory, or at least work with it outside of MySQL?

If you work with that data in memory, you will see a significant performance gain.

Comment: seconded, 8000 nodes will easily fit in memory.

Comment: Good call! The table with the node information is simply rows of fromNode, toNode. I will investigate simply loading it into memory..maybe just a big Dictionary structure.

Comment: As a simple test, I have loaded the MySQL into memory by simply using ENGINE=MEMORY on the CREATE TABLE definition. Same code now completes in about 2.5 seconds!

Comment: A bit late to the party, but are you using prepared statements for your query? Should be able to shave a little SQL processing time with that, especially in the in-memory variation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Queue import Queue

def traverse_path(fromNode, toNode, nodes):
    def getNeighbours(current, nodes):
        return nodes[current] if current in nodes else []

    def make_path(toNode, graph):
        result = []
        while 'Root' != toNode:
            result.append(toNode)
            toNode = graph[toNode]
        result.reverse()
        return result

    q = Queue()
    q.put(fromNode)
    graph = {fromNode: 'Root'}

    while not q.empty():
        # get the next node and add its neighbours to queue
        current = q.get()
        for neighbor in getNeighbours(current, nodes):
            # use neighbor only continue if not already visited
            if neighbor not in graph:
                graph[neighbor] = current
                q.put(neighbor)

        # check if destination
        if current == toNode:
            return make_path(toNode, graph)
    return []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nodes = {
        'E1123': ['D111', 'D222', 'D333', 'D444'],
        'D111': ['C01', 'C02', 'C04'],
        'D222': ['C11', 'C03', 'C05'],
        'D333': ['C01'],
        'C02': ['B1'],
        'B1': ['A3455']
    }
    result = traverse_path('E1123', 'A3455', nodes)
    print result

['E1123', 'D111', 'C02', 'B1', 'A3455']
```

If you replace your SQL queries with a dictionary of lists (and that would be the tricky part), you will get this performance.

Comment: Awesome Hugh. I've been getting good performance with an in memory table. I will try the next step. There are about 14K connections and this will eventually be a web app so I need to think carefully about how the load into memory works..

Comment: I've found that my code was similar to yours Hugh however yours is certainly more elegant. Apart from a locale-dependent spelling of 'neighbour/neighbor', the only extra suggestion I would have for the above is to call result.reverse() in make_path as this returns a list in the order fromNode -> toNode

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that machine has more than one core, doesn't it?  Run it in parallel.

[Python Threading](http://www.wellho.net/solutions/python-python-threads-a-first-example.html)

Comment: I think you mean Python Multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, doesn't BFS involve marking nodes you've already seen so you don't visit them again?

Comment: It does. If the node has already been placed in parent[], then it has been seen before, and so it is not put in the queue to act on again.

Comment: Oh I see. I missed that, sorry. Still, would be cheaper to put that flag into each node than to manipulate an ever-growing set.