# 50 million+ Rows of Data - CSV or MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, optimization, csv

I have a CSV file which is about 1GB big and contains about 50million rows of data, I am wondering is it better to keep it as a CSV file or store it as some form of a database. I don't know a great deal about MySQL to argue for why I should use it or another database framework over just keeping it as a CSV file. I am basically doing a Breadth-First Search with this dataset, so once I get the initial "seed" set the 50million I use this as the first values in my queue.

Thanks,

Comment: That's about 21.5 bytes per row. What are the fields? Please confirm that there's only one type of data record. Please explain """I am basically doing a Breadth-First Search with this dataset, so once I get the initial "seed" set the 50million I use this as the first values in my queue."""

Comment: **"It depends"** on what you are doing with the data. Provide more information to get better/useful answers.

Comment: @John it should be smaller now actually since before I was tabbing it for testing, till I realized I could do some manipulation of the data in MATLAB. What I'm doing with the data is I have say a list of 1000 user ids from Twitter, call it L1, and a copy of it called L2. Then I use L1 to create a social graph, by taking one user from that list, looking up all his friends, and appending it to the list. I do the same for the other  999 users in L1. Then remove the 1000 users from L1, and duplicates, then send them to L2, and remove duplicates. Then repeat with the new L1. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that there are a wide variety of benefits to using a database over a CSV for such large structured data so I would suggest that you learn enough to do so. However, based on your description you might want to check out non-server/lighter weight databases. Such as SQLite, or something similar to JavaDB/Derby... or depending on the structure of your data a non-relational (Nosql) database- obviously you will need one with some type of python support though.

Comment: I looked into SQLite it might work, if not what other people are advising might be feasible and faster to work with it in RAM.

Comment: @eWizardII, If you have enough RAM for the job **definately** work with it in RAM

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search on something graph-ish (since you mention Breadth-First Search) then a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) might prove useful.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just going to slurp in everything all at once? If so, then CSV is probably the way to go. It's simple and works.

If you need to do lookups, then something that lets you index the data, like MySQL, would be better.

Comment: With 50M rows, I would also pay attention to performance. It might be faster reading those 50M from a database instead of reading 50M text lines and doing all the parsing yourself.

Comment: It is a CSV file, so parsing should be 'trivial'. If it was something like an XML file, then yes I would agree: Coding simplicity would win out!

Comment: @Greg Hewgill It's certainly something that should be compared if reading in the CSV is too slow, but I wouldn't assume that MySQL would be faster. Either way something is getting the data off of disk. Parsing a CSV is unlikely to be slower than your disk's read head. In fact, you may even be able to get a performance improvement by gzipping the CSV to trade some CPU for better effective throughput. If you're going to repeatedly need to read the whole thing in MySQL may cause it to be cached in memory more effectively than the OS's IO caching, but again, you'd need to measure to be sure.

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves: When you do any lookups, a database is actually much faster than a normal file with a index. The reason for that is that (classic) databases also minimize disk operations by using [B+ trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree). Though here the data is just 1GB, so the best approach would be to load it all into memory from the start.

Comment: @THC4k I never said to use a file with an index. I said to use a file if he's going to slurp everything in at once, in which case a B-tree provides no advantage.

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves: What I meant is that databases are not only faster because they built a index (which you could do yourself as well), but because they are also good at swapping data between ram and disk -- which is much harder to do yourself. So even if both the db and cvs read the whole file, the db still has extra optimizations.

Comment: @THC4k read my comment to Greg Hewgill. For a single big read of everything it's unlikely that a database would be faster than just reading the CSV in directly, unless you let it pre-cache the data which is arguably cheating -- you'd effectively be giving the DB a "head start" by letting it read the data in before you start measuring.

Answer (score 1):

From your previous questions, it looks like you are doing social-network searches against facebook friend data; so I presume your data is a set of 'A is-friend-of B' statements, and you are looking for a shortest connection between two individuals?

If you have enough memory, I would suggest parsing your csv file into a dictionary of lists. See [Can this breadth-first search be made faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753257/can-this-breadth-first-search-be-made-faster)

If you cannot hold all the data at once, a local-storage database like SQLite is probably your next-best alternative.

There are also some python modules which might help:

- graph-tool  http://projects.skewed.de/graph-tool/
- python-graph  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-graph/1.8.0
- networkx  http://networkx.lanl.gov/
- igraph  http://igraph.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look into those I think I have enough RAM for storing it there, since the file ideally won't exceed 2GB anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about some key-value storages like MongoDB